# from itertools import product: the result is not a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, product, python-itertools

I am wondering why `list(prod)` is an empty list? But a print it out the `print(type(list(prod)))` is an list and `print(list(prod))` did show a list with 64 tuples.

```
from itertools import product
a = [1, 2]
b = [3,4]
c = [5,6]
prod = product(a, b, c,repeat=2) # 
print(list(prod))
print(type(list(prod)))

mylist = list(prod)
print(mylist)

y = 0
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
    y += 1
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `product` is a generator, and it gets exhausted once its been iterated upon. The first time this generator is iterated when you are calling `print(list(prod))` and then when you again try to call `print(type(list(prod)))` there is no entity left in the iterator. A better approach would be:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]

prod = product(a, b, c,repeat=2)
prod_list = list(prod) # Generator exhausted only once.

print(prod_list)
print(type(prod_list))
# Make any amount of calls to prod_list
```